# SPF - Adding lots of IPs

Tags: email, spf

I have 8 IPs in different ranges to add to my SPF records. All are subdomains

```
mta1.domain.com
mta2.domain.com
```

and so on.

I can't add each IPv4 to domain.com txt due to limitations. How else can I add all these IPs?

Comment: What limitations do you refer to?

Answer (score 3):

I presume you are referring to the limit of TXT records only being able to hold strings up to 255 characters? Luckily you can chain multiple strings together, which each individual string can contain up to 255 characters.

```
example.net.    IN    TXT    "v=spf1 some.ip.addresses" "more.ip.addresses" "even.more.addresses ?all"
```

See also https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00356/0/Can-I-have-a-TXT-or-SPF-record-longer-than-255-characters.html

This is also what you end up having to do with 2048 bit DKIM keys.

Comment: If I enter too many IPs then mail-tester.com shows "Junk encountered in record"

Comment: Any chance that you ended up creating a broken record? I just created a txt record for the domain shv25.se, containing 16 ipv4 adresses and 4 ipv6 adresses, without mail-tester.com having any problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Either
 1. Get a better DNS hosting provider.
 2. Set an A record to cover all your senders which includes all your senders ip addresses.
 3. Abuse `_include:$myothertxtrecord.example.com`.